# algorithm: digit substitution based on the same sequence

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I can't seem to get a handle on my study assignment.
I'm stuck on the pointer search method. But, I'm thinking about where to change these numbers. I end up with a million if and for.

I have an array of numbers, let's say `int[] numbers = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };`

I need to make it beautiful. Beautiful is where some number (possibly zero) in a row is first 0. All the others are 1.

**For example:** **001111** is beautiful, but **00001011** is not.

I can replace each digit with the opposite digit. It is necessary to output the minimum value of replaces, in order to make the array beautiful.

**Ex.** 0110

Output: 1

**Ex.** 11

Output: 0

**Note**
In the first example we can replace the last digit, then the target will look like 0111. In the second example, the original target is already beautiful.

what direction should I be thinking in?
Now I can only find the left range which consists of 0. And in the right range 0 is replaced by 1.

```
static void FindZeroSegment(int[] numbers, out int start, out int end)
{
    start = -1;
    end = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == 0)
        {
            if (start == -1)
            {
                start = i;
            }
            end = i;
        }
        else
        {
            if (start != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static int CountOnesInRightSegment(int[] numbers, int startIndex)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
            numbers[i] = 1;
    }

    return count;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
// Output 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1

    int start;
    int end;
    FindZeroSegment(numbers, out start, out end);
    
    int rightSegment = CountOnesInRightSegment(numbers, end);

    foreach (var item in numbers)
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't that simply the number of zeroes after the first one is encountered, when counting from the left?

Comment: It would have been better to [edit your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77327091/algorithm-replace-digits-in-array-based-on-the-same-sequence) with this information rather than deleting and making a new one.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError replacing a lone zero on the right, can remove a lone one on the left. Which is the approach I would recommend, use two pointers to find the next 0 from the right, and the next 1 from the left. If the pointers have crossed paths, exit. Otherwise swap them.

Comment: Though you could probably simplify that slightly by counting the number of ones, then counting the number of zeros that are in the last N places.

Comment: @gunr2171 sir,  why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from *degenerated case*: *all zeroes* array is a beautiful one, and it takes

```
// Let me use Linq, but you can sum in a loop if you want
int current = numbers.Sum();
int result = current;
```

operations to make initial `numbers` array to be beautiful all zeroes (we should change every `1` into `0`).
Now, let's check how many operations require to make array

- all zeroes except the last item
- all zeroes except the last two items
  ...
- all ones:

```
for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  if (number[i] == 1)
    current -= 1;
  else
    current += 1;

  result = Math.Min(result, current);
}
```

Put all these fragments together:

```
private static int Solve(int[] numbers) {
  int current = numbers.Sum();
  int result = current;

  for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (numbers[i] == 1)
      current -= 1;
    else
      current += 1;

    result = Math.Min(result, current);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Demo:

```
int[][] tests = new int[][] {
  new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
  new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
  new int[] { 1, 1 },
  new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 } 
};
      
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"[{string.Join(", ", test)}] : {Solve(test)}"));  
      
Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] : 2
[0, 1, 1, 0] : 1
[1, 1] : 0
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1] : 2
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ex27d0)

Time complexity: `O(n)`

Space complexity: `O(1)`

Comment: if we take the three 0's in your first test ```int[] numbers = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };``` 
the answer will still be **2**. 
The correct answer is **3**.

Comment: @rinyasuper: the correct answer for `{ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 }` is **2**: `{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }`: we can turn first two `1` into `0`

Comment: oh, I apologize, my bad. A few unsuccessful hours on the task have made me even dumber.